# How to query two table in coredata at same time

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

there are two object:

```
@interface A : NSManagedObject{
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sub_id;
}

@interface B : NSManagedObject{
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *id;
}
```

can i do something in core-data like follows in sql?

```
select b.* from b,a where a.sub_id = b.id
```